# How to directly show that Figure 8 injective immersion is not a monomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

I'm working in the category of smooth manifolds. The injective immersion that takes the open unit interval $(0,1)$ to the figure 8 is a well-known example of an injective immersion that is not an embedding. Now embeddings are the monomorphisms in our category. So the figure 8 immersion (let's call it $f$) must not be a monomorphism. Hence, there must exist two distinct maps $g_1,g_2:X\rightarrow (0,1)$ such that $f\circ g_1 = f\circ g_2$. What is an example of such maps?

Comment: How are you quantifying $X$?

Comment: Hi Neal, it is an object in the category of smooth manifolds (what else could it be?) :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f : X \to Y$ be any smooth map whatsoever. Suppose $f (x) = f (x')$. Then $x$ and $x'$, considered as smooth maps $1 \to X$, have the property that $f \circ x = f \circ x'$. So if $f$ is monic in the category of manifolds it must be injective.

Conversely, suppose $f : X \to Y$ is an injective smooth map. Then, for any smooth maps $g, g' : T \to X$, if $f \circ g = f \circ g'$, then $g = g'$ (because smooth maps are determined by their action on points). Thus any injective smooth map is monic. In particular the figure-8 injective immersion is monic.

Comment: Thanks Zhen Lin, but I believe that is not my question. I am asking for two distinct maps $g_1,g_2$ that compose with the figure 8 map $f$ so that $f\circ g_1 = f\circ g_2$. Otherwise, you can tell me that no such maps $g_1, g_2$ exist, which would make $f$ a monomorphism, and in my understanding an embedding, which is false.

Comment: I prove that no such maps exist in my second paragraph. I believe your understanding is incorrect: if I recall correctly, the _regular_ monomorphisms are embeddings.

Comment: Thanks, just saw your edit. Aha, that makes sense! Thanks again.